# Is there any way to avoid raising an error from thread when Thread.abort_on_exception is true?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Ruby 2.0 mingw32
Windows 7

I want to execute this code but I can't avoid raising the error to main thread from t thread.
I know it works correctly when Thread.abort_on_exception is false.
But for this case, I want to keep it true.
Is it possible?

```
Thread.abort_on_exception = true
4.times{|i|
  Thread.new{
    begin
      t = Thread.new{
        sleep(10 - (Time.now.to_f % 10))
        raise "same error"
      }
      t.abort_on_exception = false
      t.join
    rescue
      print "do it again %d\n" % i
      retry
    end
  }
}
sleep 60
```

Any advices are very welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The docs seem clear enough that no: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Thread.html#method-c-abort_on_exception-3D

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked here though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the [example in the doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Thread.html#method-c-abort_on_exception-3D), setting it to true would basically make exceptions stop *every* thread. If that is correct, rescuing it after the sleep 60 statement is probably the best you can do:

```
begin
  # your code here
rescue
  puts "rescued"
end
```

Comment: I see. Now I know all I can do is overwrite the Thread class or make my thread class. Thank you.